# section scripts vs script-tag in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What is the difference of both statements concerning the section Scripts and script-tag? NOT the content inside the scripts that does not interest me.

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render(Bundles.Scripts.Validation)
}
```

vs

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Validation.js")"></script>
```

Comment: The first will bundle and minify your script in release mode (depending on your settings), the second wont. The first (`@section Scripts`)  allows your to render the scripts in the layout pages placeholder (as defined by `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **first one** renders the `<script>` tag where you have `@RenderSection("Scripts")` in your layout.

This **is preferred** when you don't have to include a script for all pages.

Also `@Scripts.Render` will minify and bundle your scripts. Usually this is used **at the end of `body`** tag so that Views can get the scripts after the DOM is rendered.

The **second one** remains where you use the `<script>` tag.

If you use it in `Layout`, the script is included in all pages (e.g. `jQuery`).

---

Let's take an example

```
 <!-- HTML in Layout, before Scrip -->
 @RenderBody()
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.min.js")"></script>
 @RenderSection("Scripts")
 <!-- HTML after Script -->
```

Here, if the script make use of `jQuery` you want to included with `section` because `jQuery` is included **before `section`**.

If you include with `<script>` in your view you will give an error, that `jQuery` is missing, because is included **before `jQuery`**.

Comment: So @RenderSection will render my script bundles at end of the body?

Comment: @Elisa, `@RenderSection("Scripts")` will render the scripts at the location you place it in the layout. Its normal to put it immediately before the closing `</body>` tag, but some prefer to place it in the `<head>`

Comment: therefore I had to put my script-tag with the .min files after the RenderSection

Comment: @Elisa The `section` is preferred when you don't have to include a script for all pages. If you want the script to be present in all pages, you can included after/before  `RenderSection` or in another place, depends how you use it.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to define sections in you _layout.cshtml file for specific content. It is generally believed that styles belong to `<head>` and scripts belong before `</body>`. Your mileage may vary.

If you just output `<script>` it will go with all the content and not where you might want it to be.
And if script inside view depends on something (jquery) and in your layout you have

```
@renderBody()    
<script src=jquery.js></script>
@renderSection("scripts",required:false)
```

then you are screwed (-:

Comment: So when I have  @RenderSection("Scripts",false); and my .js file I want to include and it must run AFTER other scripts, I must put my script-tag after the @RenderSection statement, right?

Comment: yes. @renderSection just renders a defined section from your view