# How to use modal bootstrap in identity razor pages in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, bootstrap-modal, asp.net-core-identity

I want to call the registration or login of individual Microsoft identity on the main page of my site using bootstrap modal. Everything goes well until the validations are applied and it is transferred from the modal page to a non-modal one and the validation calls

`_Mainlayout` in `Shared` folder:

```
<a class="model-btn" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i></a>


    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Register</h5>
                    <a class="fa fa-window-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="register-modal">
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function OnComplete() {
            $(".modal").modal("hide");
        }
        $(function () {
            $('a.model-btn').on('click', function () {
                $('.modal-body').load(`/Identity/Account/Register`);
            });
        })
    </script>
```

`Register` page in `Areas/Identity/Pages/Account` folder

```
@page

@model RegisterModel


@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Register";
}

<div class="col-lg-12">
    <form id="registerForm" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post" class="ajax-contact form-style6" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-update="register-modal" data-ajax-complete="OnComplete">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" asp-for="Input.Email" placeholder="name@example.com" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" asp-for="Input.Password" placeholder="password" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" placeholder="password" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <button class="vs-btn" type="submit">Register</button>
        <p class="form-messages"></p>
    </form>
</div>
```

https://qawithexperts.com/article/asp-net/bootstrap-pop-up-modal-validation-in-aspnet-core-mvc/363

[Modal form validation in asp.net core 2.1 and Razor pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53635411/modal-form-validation-in-asp-net-core-2-1-and-razor-pages)

Comment: How is your _MainLayout used and rendered and please show your error more clearly . I tested with a brand new app and the modal is rendered partly wrong but validations right. https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1TW7.png