# JQuery in ASP.NET MVC 5 function does not get called after page load

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5, and in my view I have the following `<script>` elements at the top of the body:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        alert('jQuery Load.If this message box shows it means jQuery is correctly referenced and can be used on this page');

        $('#pid').change(function () {
            alert("@Model.ProjectFilter"); // <--This stops if I have a breakpoint but no alert message
            @Model.ProjectFilter = $(this).val();
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want this function to fire when the select element is changed on this dropdown:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ProjectFilter", null, htmlAttributes: new { @id="pid", @class = "form-control" })
```

When I debug a breakpoint in that function is triggered when the page is loading, but I never get alert boxes fired. Nothing happens when I select from the dropdown. I have found a bunch of script examples that only give a snippet, and I feel like I'm missing stuff before my `$('pid').change`.

I did put the bundle @Render stuff in my _layout page here:

```
<html>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Project Information Browser</title>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</head>
```

What is the proper script syntax for declaring functions to run on the client side?

Comment: 1. You aren't closing your brackets on your event handler function. 2. If you need to model bind a value that will toggle with the `onchange`, create a hidden input and use it's html id or some other property to set it when firing the `onchange` event. I take it you are using Razor in your view?

Comment: @PaulGibson: Try to open debug console in the browser (usually F12) and reload your page. Check for any possible errors.

Comment: @Victor I see an error when I inspect the page regarding invalid left hand on assignment, and the script in the rendered html page has a 0 =, so my `@Model` reference is apparently not working.

Comment: @RyanWilson, thank you I did not catch that.  I've edited my code block, added another couple of lines.  The altert box for JQuery never gets called, so perhaps something is not loading up correctly?

Comment: @PaulGibson Razor syntax is used on the server side when creating the view, it's not going to be recognized client side, what happens if you try using this: `$('#pid').change(function () {
            alert($(this).val()); 
  });`, does it show the alert?

Comment: @RyanWilson, yes that now shows the alert.  I also changed my script src to be `"~/Scripts/ . . ."` so that I'm referencing my server elements rather than the jquery.com site.  So then how do I change the selected value that gets posted back to the controller?  I thought somehow that JQuery could do this for me.

Comment: @RyanWilson I don't understand this.  The select box is already mapped to my viewmodel, and I also need a hidden field my model.  I'll use it but I am not grokking this client to server mapping that well.

Comment: @PaulGibson, since you're mapping the drop down to your model already, my bad, you don't need the jQuery at all. Whatever the drop down is set to will be passed to your controller on a form submission and if the control is inside the form

Comment: @RyanWilson then I'm doing something wrong with the Dropdown (its the second code block, in the question, just a single line).  I think the syntax is that the view model binding is on the first argument (ie, `"ProjectFilter"`), is that right?  The submitted form as passed into the controller does not retain that value, thus my JQuery attempt.

Comment: @RyanWilson I have two different forms . . . the dropdown is in form 1 but I also want the form 2 submit to get that value.  So I think that the JQuery  with a hidden field is the only way to do that.

Comment: @PaulGibson So, you are trying send back two forms at once?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250633/discussion-between-paul-gibson-and-ryan-wilson).

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem you're experiencing is the way you load your view's JS. The _Layout is loading jQuery so that you can remove the explicit reloading from your view. In order to sync view JS loading with the Layout, put view's JS in scripts section:

```
@section scripts{
   $(function () {
     alert('jQuery Load.If this message box shows it means jQuery is correctly referenced and can be used on this page');

     $('#pid').change(function () {
        alert("@Model.ProjectFilter"); // <--This stops if I have a breakpoint but no alert message
        @Model.ProjectFilter = $(this).val();
     });
  });
}
```

The usual place where the Layout should render the scripts section is **after @RenderBody()** or in the footer: thus you ensure that RenderBody() has rendered the view's body and you have all the referenced elements presented:

```
<footer>
  @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</footer>
```

This detailed answer could provide you with more details: [What is @section scripts and what it is used for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53932368/8327106)

Comment: Interesting, thanks for that.  I inserted your code in place of mind and found that I need the `<script type=javascript>` still enclosing the contents of `@section scripts` inside the brackets.  But the issue that I'm having persists, I think because my hidden field is not registering properly, or I"m not accessing the value to set it properly.

Comment: Try also accessing your view model property value in JS with **'@Html.Raw(Model.ProjectFilter)'**