# Syntax Error: Unexpected token '<' when attempting to load custom JavaScript in ASP.NET WebAPI project

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

This is my first .NET WebAPI project, so apologies if this an obvious issue, but I have created a new .NET WebAPI project in Rider, and am following the [Microsoft Learn tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-enable-qrcodes?view=aspnetcore-7.0#adding-qr-codes-to-the-2fa-configuration-page) for the Identity Service to include a `qr.js` JavaScript file which should display a QR code on the page. This tutorial regards the .NET Scaffold Identity option to add in a template page which contains the relevant layout for enabling Multifactor Authentication.

However, when I load the app and navigate to this page, any custom JavaScript which I have added does not correctly load. Instead, the contents are a placeholder app page (which I assume is generated for 404s under the site root.

As per the instructions, I added a line to `@section Scripts` to include my custom JavaScript:

```cs
@section Scripts {
    
    @await Html.PartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial")
    
    <script src="~/lib/qrcode.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/qr.js"></script>
}
```

This is my `wwwroot/` and `Areas/` structure in the project.

[image: Screenshot of project asset layout]

The error I receive can be seen in the browser inspector:

[image: Screenshot of web browser inspector displaying error]

The comment in the returned HTML suggests I should be doing something or placing the JavaScript file(s) elsewhere, but the Microsoft documentation doesn't allude to this.

**Edit:** The contents to `qr.js` are below, as it wasn't made clear in my original post what the that was:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    
    const uri = document.getElementById("qrCodeData").getAttribute('data-url');
    
    new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrCode"),
        {
            text: uri,
            width: 256,
            height: 256
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: "qr.js" is not a javascript file.

Comment: Have you tried to add `type="text/javascript"` in your script render?

Comment: @pcalkins While I appreciate the content of the screenshot I provided would allude to it not being a JavaScript file, I assure you, it is.

@XinranShen Adding the `type` attribute makes no difference, but it's a worthy addition regardless. I feel like this issue is path-based, but I can't find any documentation which suggests the fix.

Comment: the error suggests that the first character may be "<"... you should include the qr.js file in your post.

Comment: I've included the contents in the main question. As you can see, it's just a JavaScript function invocation.

Comment: according to the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37727972/what-is-section-scripts-and-what-it-is-used-for  You can't use section in partial view, "Just be aware that Partial Views are not able to use the section element by default."  Is that where you are placing the section?

Comment: if so, just remove the "@section...{}" bit.

Comment: This isn't in a partial file. The file in question is EnableAuthenticator.cshtml. I happened to have _QrCodePartial.cshtml highlighted when that source tree screenshot was taken, but that is not the file in question.

Comment: actually i don't find error in the information you provided in your question.